# Return HTTP status codes in R Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have an R Shiny app that loads data based on the currently logged-in user. The particular method of authentication happens upstream and it forwards a user ID in the HTTP headers.

In *server.R*, I make user-specific data available as a reactive data object, basically like this:

```
available_data <- reactivePoll(
  intervalMillis = 3600000, # one hour
  session = session,
  checkFunc = function() {
    "" # don't bother invalidating ever
  },
  valueFunc = function() {
    user_id <- fromJSON(as.list(session$request)$HTTP_SHINY_SERVER_CREDENTIALS)$user_id

    if (user_id %in% authorized_users) {
      return(get_data(user_id))
    } else {
      stop(safeError("Not authorized"))
    }
  }
)
```

Then I use `available_data()` for data tables, plots, etc. This is fine.

When `user_id` **isn't** one in the authorized users in the list, though, I get the specified red error message in place of the table/plot. The unauthorized user still sees all of the navigation, tabsets, non-reactive content, etc. What I'd rather do is just preempt all rendering of the page and return a 403 status code to the user's browser. I can't find a way to do this though.

Is there a way to raise an exception in a Shiny app such that the UI isn't rendered at all?

Comment: You can have "hollow UI" without authentication, but the `session$request` is only available within the `server` component. I suggest you have two options: (1) use `shinyjs` to hide/show all (important) components based on the presence of some value, though it would still be possible for a nosey user to see the raw HTML; or (2) use [dynamic UI (`uiOutput`, `insertUI`, `removeUI`, ...)](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) to populate the `ui` component only after the user is authorized. (You'd be migrating most of the ui component to within a server conditional.)

Comment: (Caution on option 2: make sure you really control reactivity, otherwise you can really mess up the user experience.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using shinyjs to start the session with all UI hidden, and then show the UI only if an authorized user makes the connection.

For example, the following app only show UI to logged-in users. I'm substituting the authorization status with radio buttons to simplify the example, but the logic is the same.

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  h1("User Authentication Example"),
  radioButtons("login", "Login:", c("Logged out", "Logged in")),
  div(id = "logged.in.ui",
    p("You are logged in")
  ) %>% shinyjs::hidden()
)

# server.R

library(shinyjs)

function(input, output) {

  # Showing/hiding UI depending on login status.
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    if (input$login == "Logged in") {
      shinyjs::show("logged.in.ui")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("logged.in.ui")
    }
  })

}
```

Note the `%>% shinyjs::hidden` in the UI portion of the above app. This functions to hide all UI within the logged.in.ui div using JavaScript when the session is created and before the login status is checked in the server. Toggling the radio buttons is observed in the server, and the UI content of the logged.in.ui div is shown or hidden depending on the login status.